# Visual Studio search in Class Diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, class-diagram

Is there any way to search for a keyword in class diagram (.cd) files in Visual Studio?

When I do ctrl + F it brings search in files box which is searching on entire project files. I would like to focus on found elements on class diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it kind of helped me:

> The .Net Class Diagram does not support searching within the diagram. 
>   There is a way to use the Class View to solve your scenario.  If you
>   open the class view and use the search ability to find the class you
>   are interested, then right click View Class Diagram, if you have the
>   Class Diagram open, the class will be selected.

[source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7739abfd-5bf2-4927-b28f-aab2adc853d0/search-a-class-by-name?forum=vsclassdesigner)